# Action script trees

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tree

i have a directory path of the computer and i will like to create a tree of that directory path.

For example, If i have a directory path of the desktop, i will like to create a tree of all the folders in the desktop and the subfolders.

The only way i can think of is to create a fileSystemTree object and set the directory to the path i want. If i were to set the directory as Desktop, it immediately show the folders under the desktop directory and not the Desktop root folder first.

Answer (score 1):

So you'll need to use Tree control.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d80.html

The trick is going to be adding the child nodes at runtime upon clicking open.  A dataProvider has several methods that you implement on a dataProvider for retrieving the children.  That's not to hard by creating your own dataProvider, but that's the first step.  Write a FileCollection that conforms to the model.  Read the manual and it should be pretty easy.